# Iterating through a list of lists,skip the first list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop

The first list within my list of lists looks something like this

```
[['QGC', 'WPL', '110'], ['0', '1', '0', '16', '0', '0', '0', '0', '35.650418', '-78.313229', '100.000000', '1'], ['1', '0', ........
```

I want to skip the first list within my for loop, and compare the first element of the next list with another list. I have this code so far but don't think this is correct or efficient because I keep getting the following error

```
 print(lines[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code:

```
for lines in allrecords[1:len(allrecords):1]:
    for i, num in enumerate(linesOfFileToChange):
        #print(num)
        print(lines[0])
```

Comment: What is the expected output like?

Comment: Make sure all of the lists in `allrecords` actually have one or more elements. Also `allrecords[1:]` is the same as `allrecords[1:len(allrecords):1]`

Comment: You are assuming that each sublist (`lines`) has the same length of `linesOfFileToChange`.  That assumption is proving false.

Comment: The expected output is 0, then 1, then 2, then 3.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
for lines in allrecords:
    for i, num in enumerate(lines[:1]):
        # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way -

```
for index, values in enumerate(allrecords):
    if index == 0:
       continue
    value = values[0] if values else None
    print value
```

**OR**

```
new_records = allrecords[1:]
for values in new_records:
    print next(iter(values), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you want to compare lists with numbers in `allrecords`. So you want to compare first list with second, then second with third, third with fourth and so on.

```
allrecords = [
    ['QGC', 'WPL', '110'],
    ['1', '1', '0', '16', '0', '0', '0', '0', '35.650418'],
    ['2', '1', '0', '16', '0', '0', '0', '0', '35.650418'],
    ['3', '1', '0', '16', '0', '0', '0', '0', '35.650418'],
    ['4', '1', '0', '16', '0', '0', '0', '0', '35.650418'],
]

for idx_lst, lst in enumerate(allrecords[1:-1]):
    next_lst = allrecords[idx_lst+2]
    for lst_value, next_lst_value in zip(lst, next_lst):
        # do some operations here
        print lst_value, next_lst_value, "|" ,
    print ""
```

Output:

```
1 2 | 1 1 | 0 0 | 16 16 | 0 0 | 0 0 | 0 0 | 0 0 | 35.650418 35.650418 |
2 3 | 1 1 | 0 0 | 16 16 | 0 0 | 0 0 | 0 0 | 0 0 | 35.650418 35.650418 |
3 4 | 1 1 | 0 0 | 16 16 | 0 0 | 0 0 | 0 0 | 0 0 | 35.650418 35.650418 |
```

So instead of printing pairs of values you can do some operations there.